# How can I send an image in JPEG format from Java Spring Boot to Angular

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloudinary

Currently, I try to send an image file in JPEG format to Angular. However, I'm getting the following error when I send it out through Postman.

> class
> org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile
> cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
> (org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile
> is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module
> java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

The idea is to upload this image into cloudinary repository.

Here my code of the REST API:

```
@PostMapping("/uploads")
public ResponseEntity<?> upload(MultipartFile imagen) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    
    File conversion = new File(imagen.getOriginalFilename());
     imagen.transferTo(conversion);
    
    
    Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary();

    cloudinary.uploader().upload("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Pictures\\"+conversion.getName(), ObjectUtils.asMap("public_id", imagen,
            "api_key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "api_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "cloud_name", "xxxxxxx"));
    
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Any Suggest will be appreciated

Code in Angular service Layer called paciente.services.ts

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PacienteService extends GenericService<Paciente> {
private pacienteCambio: Subject<Paciente[]> = new Subject<Paciente[]> 
();
private mensajeCambio: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
super(
  http,
  `${environment.HOST}/pacientes/uploads`);
}

listarPacientes(){
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}`);
}

listarPageable(p: number, s:number){
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/pageable? 
page=${p}&size=${s}`);
}

subirImagen(archivo: string){
return this.http.post(`${this.url}/${archivo}`,archivo);
}

obtenerURLImagen(nombreImagen: String){
return this.http.get<Paciente[]> 
(`${this.url}/descripcionAssets/${nombreImagen}`);
}

listar(){
return this.http.get<Paciente[]>(this.url);
}

listarPorId(id: number){
return this.http.get<Paciente>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
}

registrar(paciente: Paciente){
return this.http.post(this.url, paciente);
}

modificar(paciente: Paciente){
return this.http.put(this.url, paciente);
}

eliminar(id: number){
return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/${id}`);
}

//////////////////////////

getPacienteCambio(){
return this.pacienteCambio.asObservable();
}

setPacienteCambio(lista: Paciente[]){
this.pacienteCambio.next(lista);
}

getMensajeCambio(){
return this.mensajeCambio.asObservable();
}

setMensajeCambio(msj: string){
this.mensajeCambio.next(msj);
}
}
```

And this is the component where I setup the REST API subirImagen

```
export class PacienteEdicionComponent implements OnInit {
id: number = 0;
edicion: boolean = false;
nombreArchivo: File;
form: FormGroup;
public archivos: any = []
public files: NgxFileDropEntry[] = [];

constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private pacienteService: PacienteService,
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.form = new FormGroup({
'id': new FormControl(0),
'nombres': new FormControl(''),
'apellidos': new FormControl(''),
'dni': new FormControl(''),
'telefono': new FormControl(''),
'direccion': new FormControl(''),
'fondo-imagen': new FormControl(''),
'email': new FormControl(''),
});

this.route.params.subscribe(data => {
this.id = data['id'];
this.edicion = data['id'] != null;
this.initForm();
});
}

for (const droppedFile of files) {
// Is it a file?
if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
fileEntry.file((file: File) => {

// Here you can access the real file
this.nombreArchivo = file;

**//This is the test i make to find out if image is uploaded**
this.pacienteService.subirImagen(**this.nombreArchivo.name**);

// You could upload it like this:
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('logo', file)

// Headers
/* const headers = new HttpHeaders({
'security-token': 'mytoken'
})

this.http.post('https://mybackend.com/api/upload/sanitize-and-save- 
logo', formData, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' })
.subscribe(data => {

// Sanitized logo returned from backend
})
**/
});

} else {
// It was a directory (empty directories are added, otherwise only 
files)
const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, fileEntry);
}
}
}


@PostMapping(value="/uploads", consumes = { 
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<?> guardarImagen(@RequestParam("adjunto") 
MultipartFile file, Integer id) throws Exception{
Paciente pac = service.listarPorId(id);
//Se valida si existe el id en la base de datos
if(pac == null) {
        
throw new ModeloNotFoundException("ID NO ENCONTRADO " + id);
}
    String fotoUsuario = file.getOriginalFilename();                
    Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary();
    cloudinary.uploader().upload(file.getBytes(), 
    ObjectUtils.asMap("public_id", file.getOriginalFilename()));
    Map result = cloudinary.api().resource(file.getOriginalFilename(), 
ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
service.actualizarFoto(id, fotoUsuario);     
return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Just a guess since I don't know cloudinary, but I doubt `"public_id", imagen` is correct. I think it expects a string there, not `imagen` which is a `MultipartFile`. I think something like `imagen.getOriginalFilename()` is more likely to work.

Comment: I can advise to send array of bytes rather than image (just convert your image to bytes before), and inside your business logic, convert those bytes back to image and save it. And also, not by this topic, better to move business logic from container to service.

Comment: i appreciate your comments. i modified i little bit my code in the Rest API by passing an string instead of a MultipartFile and the image is succesfully upload to cloudinary, but now the issue is in angular doesn't make it as postman does. Maybe i'm not passing the rest service correctly. look,                                           
    subirImagen(archivo: String){
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/uploads?imagen=${archivo}`,archivo);
  }

Comment: If you are uploading an image to Cloudinary then you can upload it as it is, no need to convert it to a different format. You can easily convert it after upload using Cloudinary's transformations. See `https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#delivering_in_a_different_format`. Or you can use Cloudinary's incoming transformation to tell them to convert to jpg first and then upload, see `https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformations_on_upload#incoming_transformations`.

Comment: thanks Tom. Yes indeed, the problem now, isn't to upload the image, i already got it, however as i told to Federico in comment above, my problem is maybe i don't know how to pass the uploads RestAPI correctly to angular because doesn't angular doesn't send the image to cloudinary as postman successfully does.

Comment: your upload is already happening in the backend based on your code are you trying to send the upload response to your angular frontend? What error are you getting?

Comment: that's weird, i don't get any message into the console when sending a testing, but when checking in cloudinary, it doesn't display the image sent from angular through the Rest API.

Comment: hmm... I'd need to see your full setup, can you explain what your exact setup is with relevant code examples? Are you using Angular for front-end and Java as back-end?

Comment: yes for sure tom. I edit my inquiry above. pls check if you're so kind the code. thanks bro.

Comment: thanks for that, so I'm still a bit confused, are you trying to upload the image from your Frontend code or backend? If frontend, I do not see any calls to Cloudinary to make the upload.

Comment: thanks tom. look i add the code above of my rest API where cloudinary is coded.

Comment: @cherokeexxx1 The `cloudinary.uploader().upload` is a backend implement (e.g., Node.JS). In case you would like to perform frontend upload, you can use the javascript fetch [POST method as described in this document](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload) and [sample here](https://www.postman.com/cloudinary-docs/workspace/cloudinary-collections/request/16080251-e6b8782c-e6c2-4a05-85e4-9209a51b8c0e?ctx=code).